# Convert bookmark folder names to tags in Firefox bookmarks JSON export

Tags: shell, firefox, scripting, jq, bookmarks

I used to use *Google Chrome* bookmarks for a very long time, heavily utilizing its tagging.
Now I would like to switch to plain *Firefox* bookmarking. I exported my bookmarks from
`chrome://bookmarks` (*HTML* export) and imported them in *Firefox*. So far so good. But sadly what
was a tag in *Chrome* is a bookmark folder in *Firefox* now! I ended with many hundreds of
bookmark folders and thousands of duplicates across them and, of course, no tags at all.

*Firefox* can export bookmarks as *JSON* so I managed to find a way to restructure
the *JSON* export so that after importing what is the *Firefox* bookmark folder will be
bookmark tag again. I tried some ways to do so using `jq(1)` but failed completely while
I have to cope with levels of nesting in the bookmarks *JSON* export I do not know
how to cope with yet (yes, I am completely new to `jq(1)`).

Deduplication of bookmarks can (hopefuly) be done using some of the *Firefox* addons for
the task. Therefore all what I need now is to convert bookmark folder paths in bookmark *JSON* export
to bookmark tags.

Of course, if "deduplication" (by concatening the bookmark folders as tags for every single
*URL*) was possible, it would be fine too. If `jq(1)` is not the right tool for such a task
any other solution is welcome of course. It is just "single shot" task for me but may be
very useful to anybody who would like to migrate their bookmarks from *Chrome* bookmarks
to *Firefox*.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the data you're working with? And is de-duplication your only goal or other transformations as well? It would also be helpful if you gave the desired output along with your input sample.

Comment: We need a sample. If you give a sample, it's no problem